# Find the solution of y = f(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the solution $y = f(x)$  of: $$ x^2 + y^2 - x^3 = 0 $$
Near the following points $(5,10)$,$(10,-30)$

I think I need to use the implicit function theorem and I tried this

- First for the definition the function has continuous partial derivatives
- Applying $(5,10)$: hence, $F(5,10) = 0$
- $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(5,10) = 2\cdot 10 = 20 \neq 0 $

Hence by the implicit function theorem it has a unique solution in the form of $y(x)$ around $(5,10)$

But what is this solution?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add = 0 Thankss @lulu

Comment: What do you mean by solution? Do you want to express $y$ in terms of $x,$ or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$x^2 + y^2 - x^3 = 0 \implies y^2=x^3-x^2$$

Therefore you have two functions $$y=\pm \sqrt {x^3-x^2}$$

Therefore near the point $(5,10)$ you pick the positive sign and near the point $(10,-30)$ you pick negative sign.

Answer (score 3):

The two solutions would be $y = \sqrt{x^3 - x^2}$ around $(5,10)$, and $y = -\sqrt{x^3 - x^2}$ around $(10, -30)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2+ y^2- x^3= 0$ then $y^2= x^3- x^2$ so $y= \pm\sqrt{x^3- x^2}$.  Since 10 is positive the branch that passes through (5, 10) is $y= \sqrt{x^3- x^2}$.  Since -30 is negative the branch that passes through (10, -30) is $y= -\sqrt{x^3- x^2}$.